# c - how to break scanf with no enter and no string

Tags: c, scanf

I have a project for school and in it, I need to get a four digit number and then continue immediately with no enter. For example: "Enter a number: 1424" and then it just continues, and you can't enter anymore numbers, aw well as Enter key pressing should not be needed.
I tried `scanf("%4d",&num);` but it waits for Enter key.

And one more restriction is... I can't use strings in this project, so all the solutions must be without strings.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: To implement this functionality you need something like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Comment: The behavior you seek is controlled by the *terminal*, not by your program. `scanf` cannot stop your terminal from accepting more characters from the user. It doesn't "regain control" until after the user presses enter. For this you need a terminal access library like ncurses.

Comment: maybe a loop with some _getch() ?

Comment: On Unix systems, you could type the four digits and then control-D (unless you changed your terminal settings). This would send the four digits to %4d. Using %d, you'd need to add a space after the digits (safest choice).  It is all to do with terminal modes and raw vs cooked input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to organize input without Enter key press are functions `getch` and `getche` from `conio.h` header, that I suppose is not in C/C++ standard. So POSIX standard names are `_getch` and `_getche`.

With that functions you will read character - which are not strings if you process each `char` separately.

**UPDATE:**

My solution is:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char ch;    // to store an input - single char
    int number = 0; // to make number from inputs
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    int digits_cnt = 0;
    while (digits_cnt < 4)
    {
        ch = _getche();
        if (isdigit(ch))
        {
            number *= 10;  // add an order to number
            number += ch - '0';  // add a decimal digit to number
            digits_cnt++;  // count this digit to stop loop
        }
    }
    // just to check result
    printf("\nThe number %d was entered.\n", number);
    return 0;
}
```

I assume that all 4 digits should become a number, but, perhaps, you need to do something else with them.

Comment: that's perfect! thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For reading 4 digits you probably want use [char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) that will do exactly what you are asking for. You should not use scanf for interactive input you can find why in this [article](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html)

To the string part since you are typing input in ascii you are already working with strings(arrays of chars).